# Latex Recall and Precision Table

Tags: tables, formatting, pdftex, rules

I want to draw follow table on a latex but I have spend over a day now but yet to get anything close to it. I am attaching a screen short it would be great if I can get latex command to build this table.[image]

Comment: The screenshot leaves a lot of design questions open. Does columns 5 have to be so much wider than columns 3, 4, and 6? Does the font have to be sans serif (and, if so, which one?), or is the font choice irrelevant for now? Do the numeric cells have to be aligned flush-right, or would you prefer aligning the numbers on the decimal marker?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with `siunitx` to align the digits.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2} 
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An important table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|S|S|S|S|}           \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\# of class} &\multirow{2}{*}{type}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Trained Data}    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{New Data}                    \\   \cline{3-6}
 &  &{Prec.} & {Rec.} & {Prec.}  & {Rec.}              \\   \hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{5} & car& 81.8 &73.1 & 73.8   & 46.3   \\   \cline{2-6}  
 & plane & 88.3 & 80.7 & 81.1   & 72.5                 \\   \cline{2-6} 
 & camera & 98.1 & 96.4 & 95.2   &  87                 \\   \cline{2-6} 
 & cup & 42.2 & 37.5 & 31   &   22.6                   \\   \cline{2-6} 
 & landscape & 71.7 & 44.9 & 67.9   & 54.3             \\   \hline 
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Average}   & 76.42 & 66.52 &69.8 & 56.54 \\ \hline 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If colored table line in preferred (blue line is shown here), one needs to load `xcolor` with option [table].

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow,siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2} 
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An important table}
\begin{tabular}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}l!{\color{black}\vrule}S!{\color{black}\vrule}S!{\color{black}\vrule}S!{\color{black}\vrule}S} 
        \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\# of class} &\multirow{2}{*}{type}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Trained Data}    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{New Data}   \\    \cline{3-6}
 &  &{Prec.} & {Rec.} & {Prec.}  & {Rec.}   \\
    \hline 
\multirow{5}{*}{5} & car& 81.8 &73.1 & 73.8   & 46.3 \\\arrayrulecolor{blue}\cline{2-6} 
 & plane & 88.3 & 80.7 & 81.1   & 72.5  \\   \arrayrulecolor{blue}\cline{2-6}
 & camera & 98.1 & 96.4 & 95.2   &  87  \\   \arrayrulecolor{blue}\cline{2-6}
 & cup & 42.2 & 37.5 & 31   &   22.6    \\   \arrayrulecolor{blue}\cline{2-6}
 & landscape & 71.7 & 44.9 & 67.9 & 54.3 \\  \arrayrulecolor{black} \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Average}   & 76.42 & 66.52 &69.8 & 56.54 \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you a simple template, than you can improve the table fixing column width, font type, alignment. For table with many numbers package siunitx can be useful.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{clSSSSS}
\toprule
\multirow{2}*{\# of clas}   &   \multirow{2}*{type} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}    {Trained Data}    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{New Data}  \\

 &  &   {Prec.} &   {Rec.}  &   {Prec.} &   {Rec.}  \\
\midrule
\multirow{5}*{S}    &   car         &   81.8    &   73.1    &   73.8    &   46.3    \\
                &   plane       &   88.8    &   80.0    &   81.8    &   72.5    \\
                &   camera      &   98.8    &   96.0    &   95.2    &   87      \\
                &   cup         &   42.2    &   37.5    &   31      &   22.6    \\
                &   landscape   &   71.7    &   44.9    &   67.9    &   54.3    \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Average} & 76.42 &   66.52   &   69.8    &   56.54   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```